# Android mediaplayer reinitializes on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am streaming/playing already downloaded video in the `VideoView`. When I rotate the screen all the objects are reinitialized so that the video is played from the beginning or if get current position and set the position on screen rotation the video is streamed again. As the video from back end is encrypted,it takes so much time to load it resulting in a very bad user experience.
The following is what I've os far.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    Context context;
    int stopPosition = 0;
    private static MediaController mediaController;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            stopPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
            Log.d("", "savedInstanceState called" + stopPosition);
        }
        mediaController = new MediaController(context);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videotest;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d("", "onPause called");
        super.onPause();
        videoView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("", "onResume called" + stopPosition);
        videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
        videoView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        videoView.pause();
        outState.putInt("position", 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        stopPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
    }


}
```

When I used the following methods this problem is solved but some new one starts.

If I add `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` to `AndroidManifest.xml` it works perfectly except `onSaveInstanceState` is not called. I've some works to do in it so I want it be called.
Another method I used is that using `Mediaplayer` and `SurfaceView` and it works too except the `mediaplayer` not functioned correctly in some cases(Video size changes in each videos)

Basically what I would like to have is that in above code `onRestoreInstanceState` should be called and video shouldn't reinitialized(or play without a delay) in screen rotation

Comment: it creates another object

Comment: you have to save the bundle on screen orientation

Comment: save the current time on rotation in shared preferences and in onCreate method get the saved time and seek your media player to that time

Comment: That'll reinitialize the objects, I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, if we add `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` to manifest.xml then only `onConfigurationChanged` override is called, activity is not recreated. As I had one `VideoView` and a `ListView` in the screen which has parent `LinearLayout`, I changed orientation to horizontal from verical in `onConfigurationChanged`.

You have to dynamically set required views in Portrait or Landscape mode accordingly.